# Can't get dashArray to work on canvas in Leaflet 1.0.3

Tags: leaflet

`dashArray: '4 4'` works fine with `renderer: L.svg()`, but not `L.canvas()`.

The documentation says "Doesn't work on Canvas-powered layers in some old browsers.", but this happens in the very latest Chrome.

If it doesn't work it doesn't work, just curious if anyone knows of a workaround or explanation?

Comment: It's a bug in Leaflet. See https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/6277

Comment: Thanks! You're my hero of the day!

I feel like I've tried commas, but I must have done something else wrong those times. Now it works!

Glad that the bug might get fixed.

Answer (score 1):

The comment by IvanSanchez explains that the problem is a simple bug in Leaflet.

The workaround is to use commas: `dashArray: '4,4'`